# How to write correct yaml for deploying kubernetes cluster in Azure devops?

Tags: angular, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops

I am trying to establish Dockerized Angular application in azure cloud by using kubernetes but I can not do that. Everything looks fine but I can not see angular application when I enter
web url on browser.What is wrong in my Dockerfile or yml files? Can you give me some advises? I made lots of search in 2 days but I didn't find a solution.

deployment.yml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: xxx-pod
  name: xxx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xxx-pod
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
     labels:
        app: xxx-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: xxx.azurecr.io/cm-webui:v1
        name: webapp
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources: {}
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3080 
status: {}
```

service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxx-service
  labels:
    run: xxx-pod
spec:
  selector:
    app: xxx-pod
  ports:
  - port: 3080
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10 AS ui-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY my-app/ ./my-app/
RUN cd my-app && npm install @angular/cli && npm install && npm run build

FROM node:10 AS server-build
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=ui-build /usr/src/app/my-app/dist ./my-app/dist
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY server.js .

EXPOSE 3080

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

My Logs :

```
8m13s       Normal    EnsuredLoadBalancer            service/xxx-service                    Ensured load balancer
8m17s       Warning   FailedToUpdateEndpoint         endpoints/xxx-service                  Failed to update endpoint default/xxx-service: Operation cannot be fulfilled on endpoints "xxx-service": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
8m17s       Warning   FailedToUpdateEndpointSlices   service/xxx-service                    Error updating Endpoint Slices for Service default/xxx-service: failed to update xxx-service-p429q EndpointSlice for Service default/xxx-service: Operation cannot be fulfilled on endpointslices.discovery.k8s.io "xxx-service-p429q": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

Comment: This is a Kubernetes issue, not an Azure DevOps issue. Please provide more details on your Kubernetes cluster. Where is it hosted? How is ingress configured? Have you been able to get any workloads working properly? And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the service definition you exchanged `port` and `targetPort` values. `port` should be 80 and `targetPort` 3080.